# Why am I getting a message segmentation fault?

Tags: c, cs50

Using C, I am trying to implement a function that converts `word` into `mutated_word` according to the key `string_word`. eg: when `word` is `"HE"`, with the key `"QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"`, the mutated_word should become `"IT"`. But it keeps giving segmentation fault, not sure how to improve.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    string word = "HE" ;
    string string_word = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
    char mutated_word[strlen(word)]; 
    
    for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        string_word[(int)word[i] - 65] = mutated_word[i];
    }
    
    printf("%s", mutated_word);
}
```

Comment: I guess you mean `mutated_word[i] = string_word[word[i]-65]`, but you also have to terminate `mutated_word` with a \0 byte.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ok got it, thanks!!

Comment: note also: `mutated_word` has to have length `strlen(word)+1` to be able to fit the terminating \0 byte.

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to terminate the new string with *null character*.
2. Your array is too small
3. Use the correct type for indexes (`int` is not the correct one)
4. Check if the character is the letter. If not decide what to do (in my example I convert all letters to uppercase, other chars are left as they are)
5. Do not use *magic numbers*. Instead of `65` use `'A'`
6. Your assignment is wrong, you actually want something right opposite.
7. It will not work with all character encoding.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) 
{
    string word = "HE" ;
    string string_word = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM" ;
    char mutated_word [strlen(word) + 1]; 
    
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha((unsigned char)word[i]))
        {
            mutated_word[i] = string_word[toupper((unsigned char)word[i]) - 'A'];
        }
        else
        {
            mutated_word[i] = word[i];
        }
    }
    mutated_word[i] = 0;
   
    printf("%s", mutated_word); 
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4zqq98Y3n

To make it more portable:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

ptrdiff_t findIndex(const char ch, const char * restrict dict)
{
    char *result = strchr(dict, ch);
    if(!result) return -1;
    return result - dict;
}

int main (void) 
{
    string word = "He124" ;
    string string_word = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM" ;
    string dict = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYWZ";
    ptrdiff_t index;
    char mutated_word [strlen(word) + 1]; 
    
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha((unsigned char)word[i]))
        {
            index = findIndex(toupper((unsigned char)word[i]), dict);
        }
        else index = -1;
        mutated_word[i] = index == -1 ? word[i] : string_word[index];

    }
    mutated_word[i] = 0;
   
    printf("%s", mutated_word); 
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/KW8TxxEvq

Comment: You might also comment that although using `'A'` and `<ctype.h>` macros makes the code more portable, it still silently assumes that letters from `A` through `Z` form a continuous block, which is not the case in EBCDIC :)

Comment: @chqrlie added more portable version

Comment: Sorry, cannot upvote twice... yet I would remove the `restrict` which is useless in this context, and somewhat incorrect as `result` points to the same array.

Comment: I don't believe `ssize_t` has made its way into Standard C yet. Using `int` seems OK as it would take a perverse mind to set up a dictionary where `result - dict` exceeds `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @chqrlie I did not remember that ssize_t is not standard. Changed to the more standard type (and more correct as well)

Answer (score 1):

You program crashes because the assignment is in the wrong order: `string_word[(int)word[i] - 65] = mutated_word[i];` is attempting to modify a string literal, which has undefined behavior. Note also that the destination string must be 1 byte longer for the null terminator, which you must set explicitly.

Here is a more portable version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *word = "HE";
    const char *normal_word = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    const char *string_word = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
    char mutated_word[strlen(word) + 1]; 
    unsigned char c;
    const char *p;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; (c = word[i]) != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isupper(c) && (p = strchr(normal_word, c)) != NULL) {
            c = string_word[p - normal_word];
        } else
        if (islower(c) && (p = strchr(normal_word, toupper(c))) != NULL) {
            c = string_word[p - normal_word];
            c = tolower(c);
        }
        mutated_word[i] = c;
    }
    mutated_word[i] = '\0';
   
    printf("%s\n", mutated_word); 
    return 0;
}
```